# pushManager.subscribe() is not fulfilling promise

Tags: javascript, push-notification

```
'use strict';
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    console.log('Service Worker is supported');
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function() {
        return navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
    }).then(function(reg) {
        console.log('Service Worker is ready :^)', reg);
        reg.pushManager.subscribe({userVisibleOnly:true}).then(function(sub) {
            isPushEnabled = true;
            console.log('endpoint:', sub.endpoint);
        });
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Service Worker Error :^(', error);
  }); 
}
```

This is my main.js file , The problem is that the subscribe function is not working i.e the console.log function inside it not showing a value , neither the error is shown . I am following [this tutorial as it is](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/?hl=en)

Comment: If subscribe is returning a promise, you don't need to catch it again with the console.log,  just do "return reg.pushManager......", and get rid of the ,function(error) bit.

Comment: in subscribe function the console.log('endpoint': sub.endpoint) is showing nothing on the console.i have removed that additional function aswell

Comment: Don't forget to put "return reg.pushManager"  so that the promise will cascade.  But not sure this is your problem anyway, as your getting to the console.log,  what does it give if you do console.log(sub)?

Comment: Nothing . even console.log("hey") is not working there

Comment: Same with me.. how did you resolve this?